# Match anything pattern rule with dependency

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

File Name: Makefile.mk

```
%: foo
    @echo %: $@ with foo

foo:
    @echo foo
```

Run

```
$ make -f Makefile.mk test
```

Output:

```
foo
%: Makefile.mk with foo
%: test with foo
```

I am running this in GNU Make 3.81 version.
I Don't understand, why file name also printed(**%: Makefile.mk with foo**).
Can some one please explain me?

Answer (score 4):

This is because of [how makefiles are remade](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles). That is to say that

> Sometimes makefiles can be remade from other files

and

> If a makefile can be remade from other files, you probably want make to get an up-to-date version of the makefile to read in

so

> after reading in all makefiles, make will consider each as a goal target and attempt to update it.

Which then matches against your match-anything rule and triggers the way you see.

If you add an explicit `Makefile.mk: ;` target to your makefile it will override the match-anything target and prevent this.